# twitter bootstarp 3 modal faded with the background and won't work

Tags: modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created the model using bootstrap 3 but my model fades with the background and does not work.

Here is the screenshot and code!

Upload

```
<div class="modal fade" id="upload" tabinex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Upload Image</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>select an image</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample. http://jsbin.com/togozico/1/edit. Is your problem with z-index?

Comment: That was not the problem. I just didn't thought much and created model in navigation bar.
Thanks though!